# TokenMismatchException In Laravel 5 AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create a AJAX call in Laravel 5. But I am geting **TokenMismatchException** but don't know why.

My AJAX code is -

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#send").click(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
                    headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
                    type:   'POST',
                    url:    'add_question',
                    data:   { 
                                'webinar_id'        : 1,
                                'email_id'          : "any@email.com",
                                'question'          : $('#question_to_ask').val(),
                                'answer'            : "",
                                'panelist_id'       : 1,
                                'public'            : 1
                            },
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $("ul#question_list").prepend(data);
                        $("ul#question_list li:first").fadeIn("slow");
                    }
                });
    });
});
```

My Controller of Laravel 5 is-

```
public function add_question()
{
    return "OK";
    //return Request::input('question');
}
```

But getting something like this when requested-

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the `{{ csrf_token() }}` in your JavaScript? Is your JavaScript code in a blade file?

Comment: Can i see the view where you trigger the AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
   $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#send").click(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                        headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
                        type:   'POST',
                        url:    'add_question',
                        data:   { 
                                    'webinar_id'        : 1,
                                    'email_id'          : "any@email.com",
                                    'question'          : $('#question_to_ask').val(),
                                    'answer'            : "",
                                    'panelist_id'       : 1,
                                    'public'            : 1,
                                     '_token'           : '{{csrf_token()}}' 
                                },
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            $("ul#question_list").prepend(data);
                            $("ul#question_list li:first").fadeIn("slow");
                        }
                    });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Not a good header name. Should be: X-CSRF-TOKEN

Answer (score 2):

The name of the header should be `X-CSRF-TOKEN`, not `csrftoken`.

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    },
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
var ajaxCall=$.post("{{ url('add_question')}}",
{
webinar_id        : 1,
email_id          : "any@email.com",
question          : $('#question_to_ask').val(),
answer            : "",
panelist_id       : 1,
public            : 1,
_token              : '{!! csrf_token()!!}'
 });
ajaxCall.done(function(data){
 .....
});

ajaxCall.fail(function(){
....
});
```